# filter/subset/delete rows that contain character in middle of string in R

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe with a column containing peptide sequences and I want to keep only rows that have no internal "R" or "K" in their string.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    Peptide = c("ABCOIIJUHFSAUJHR", "AOFIAUKOAISDFUK", 'ASOIRDFHAOHFKK'))


df1 #check output
```

As output I would like to keep only the first row (i.e. "ABCOIIJUHFSAUJHR").

I have tried using filter (dplyr) and str_locate_all from the stringr package and length but couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Moe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the `dplyr` solution:  `str_locate` is the tidyverse equivalent to `grepl`, so the code looks like this:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(Peptide %>% str_detect("^.[^RK]*.$"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `dplyr::filter(Peptide %>% str_detect("^[^R|K]*.$"))` (because I also wanted to filter out the R|K at beginning of the string (see my comment above).

Comment: Having some familiarity with trypsin myself, I figured that was what you wanted, but it was accepting all 3 peptides when I didn't include `^.` at the beginning.  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 5):

We can skip with the first and last character (`^.`, `.$`) and match zero or more characters that are not an R or K (`[^RK]*`) in `grep` and use that to subset the dataset

```
df1[grepl("^.[^RK]*.$", df1$Peptide), , drop = FALSE]
#           Peptide
#1 ABCOIIJUHFSAUJHR
```

Comment: An edge case: single-character string: `grepl("^.[^RK]*.$", "A")`

Comment: @Frank that is a good one.  I think we have to make a `|` for those edge cases

Comment: `"^[^R|K]*.$"` is what I ended up using (I removed the `.` (full stop), because I realized that I actually also wanted to filter out K|R at the beginning.